# How to Find UNICODE Value and Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I have a table with several nvarchar(max) fields that are a mess.  I am trying to locate the "non-ascii" characters that are going to cause problems during our conversion.

I have this function that returns a table with info:

```
SQL Server 2019
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[charVal] (@inStr nvarchar(max))
    RETURNS @returnTable TABLE (
        [id]    int identity(1,1),
        [ascii] int,
        [unicode] int,
        [char]  nvarchar(5) )
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @place int=1,
        @cnt int=1,
        @max int=0

    SET @max = (SELECT [SDU_Tools].StringLength(@inStr))

    WHILE @max >= @cnt
    BEGIN
        insert into @returnTable
            SELECT 
                ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inStr, @cnt, 1)),
                UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@inStr, @cnt, 1)),
                CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inStr, @cnt, 1))) 
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1  
    END
    RETURN
END
```

I have this string: `“Friday”` and when I run it through the function I get:

| id | ascii | unicode | char |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 226 | 8220 | NULL |
| 2 | 70 | 70 | F |
| 3 | 114 | 114 | r |
| 4 | 105 | 105 | i |
| 5 | 100 | 100 | d |
| 6 | 97 | 97 | a |
| 7 | 121 | 121 | y |
| 8 | 226 | 8221 | NULL |

While the info for `Friday` is correct, the `“` and `”` are not.  ASCII 226 is neither of them, and the fact that it thinks they are the same is a bit bothering.

[This Link](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html) shows the 8221 is the HTML code, not UNICODE.
Right now I have at least identified the rows that have issues, and the codes where char=null.  Now I need to figure out how to properly identify and print that character so I can provide a list of the offending characters.

Comment: Could you clarify "*While the info for `Friday` is correct, the `and` are not.*" What is "and"?

Comment: @Schwern Sorry about that, meant to copy/paste that in and forgot.

Comment: I see that over on https://www.codetable.net/ they have it listed as the Decimal Code#, so I guess that's right.  Still don't know what the 226 is, or how to replicate the character from the UNICODE value.

Comment: I'm curious, what conversion requires ASCII only?

Comment: Moving ERP systems, and the migration process tends to break far easier than the application itself.  Non-ASCII chars are the most common issue.  Tabs, NL, CR in text fields are the next.

Answer (score 2):

[`unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns the UCS-2 or UTF-16 ([they're very similar](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=unicode-ucs-2-its-relationship-utf-16)) representation of the character.

[`“` is U+201C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm), which is 0x201C in USC-2/UTF-16, which is... 8220 in decimal. Similarly, [`”` is U+201D](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) which is 8221.

---

[`ascii`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is returning 226 because it is only looking at the first byte. The first byte of the UTF-8 representation of both characters is E2 or 226.

---

If you want to find only 7-bit ASCII characters, those are the same as the [Basic Latin block of Unicode characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/index.htm). Check for `unicode(c) <= 128`.

Comment: Slight nitpick, the representation is could be UCS-2 rather than UTF-16. It's UTF-16 only when the collation is using [Supplementary Characters (SC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#Supplementary_Characters).

Comment: Thanks, the ascii 226 makes sense now.  If I have the decimal 8220 is there a way to convert that into the “ character?

Comment: @Dizzy49 Some programming languages have libraries to turn Unicode into their closest ASCII equivalents, but I doubt SQL Server does. You could make a mapping table of Unicode characters to ASCII equivalents.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks, if more clients need this I might need to do something like that.